# How do i pass a standalone mysql container as a dependency to a service in kubernetes-helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a service for which a helm chart has been generated. This helm chart spins off zookeeper and mysql containers with which the service communicates. 
I now want to create a helm chart that spins off a platform of services of which the above service is one. When i attempt to do this, I use tags to disable the above service's dependencies that are listed in the helm chart, like so:

```
tags:
  service-zookeeper: false
  service-mysql: false
```

Now, i have a few init containers(liquibase) that populate the mysql instances created via dependencies whenever the service is deployed. I need to pass a separate, stand alone mysql container as the instance of mysql that this init container needs to populate. A similar chroots job for zookeeper exists. 
The problem I need help tackling is that I can't seem to find a way to pass the separate mysql container as the container that needs to be populated by the first service's liquibase init-container. Is there any way to do so? Any help/insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the MySQL Service's hostname and credentials for this.

Remember that the Helm YAML templates can use everything in the [Go text/template language](https://godoc.org/text/template).  That includes conditionals `{{ if ... }}...{{ else }}...{{ end }}`, among other control structures, plus most of the support functions in the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) library.  This can become verbose, but neatly solves this class of problem.

For the host name, one approach is to assert a single service name, whether installed by your chart itself or the wrapper chart.  (If the top-level chart installs MySQL, and also installs your service, they will have the same Helm release name and the same generated hostname, independently of whether MySQL is a direct dependency of your chart.)

```
- name: MYSQL_HOST
  value: {{ printf "%s-mysql.%s.svc.cluster.local" .Release.Name .Release.Namespace | quote }}
```

Another is to pass it in the `values.yaml` configuration, optionally.  The [Sprig `default` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html) is useful here.

```
- name: MYSQL_HOST
  value: {{ .Values.mysqlHostname | default (printf "%s-mysql.%s.svc.cluster.local" .Release.Name .Release.Namespace) | quote }}
```

You can use a similar approach to either find the Secret the MySQL installation saves its passwords in or reconstruct it from configuration.